# Create a draft order via rest API or graphql in shopify

Tags: rest, graphql, shopify, remix

I am developing an app for Shopify and I am new to remix. I have used [shopify-app-remix](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@shopify/shopify-app-remix). I want to create a draft order after the app is installed. I don't know how to make an API call after the app is authenticated. I found `afterAuth` in the shopify.server.js file. I have tried to run the graphql but it's not worked.

```
hooks: {
    afterAuth: async ({ session }) => {

      const { shop, accessToken } = session;

      const response = graphql(
      `
        query supplementQRCode($id: ID!) {
          product(id: $id) {
            title
            images(first: 1) {
              nodes {
                altText
                url
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `,
      {
        variables: {
          id: qrCode.productId,
        },
      }
    );


      const shop1 = {
        shop : shop,
        accessToken : JSON.stringify(accessToken),
        planId:1
      }
      await prisma.shops.create({data:shop1});

      shopify.registerWebhooks({ session });
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume there are minor corrections to code needed.

```js
// 1.
// graphql method is async so, it requires `await` infront
const response = await graphql(

// 2.
// response needs to be converted to JSON
const {
  data: { product },
} = await response.json();

// Now you can use product related data here
// product.title
console.log(product.title);
```

ref: https://shopify.dev/docs/apps/getting-started/build-qr-code-app?framework=remix#list-qr-codes

if any doubts please comment.

Comment: I have updated the code as the screenshot attached.
I don't know how to fire a rest API from the remix please help me with this. I have been stuck for the past 3 days. I am sharing a code with you if you want.

[shopify.server.js](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/43017380?key=24cea82fca81b4527be37d28bf6356ad)
[ccc.server.js](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/43017381?key=20ce7bcf6a675d0ce613b9f0a32f3366)

Comment: You can simply follow this https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-07/resources/draftorder#post-draft-orders to add draft order